# Atualizar campo LONGBLOB é possível?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um script que faz upload de imagens para uma tabela com campo `LONGBLOB`, faço upload de uma imagem qualquer e exibo-a sem problemas.

A minha pergunta é: apesar de saber que não devemos inserir imagens no `mysql`, existe um modo de fazer `UPDATE`, ou mesmo um `INSERT` através de um determinado `ID` para esse campo `LONGBLOB`? Neste caso, como eu faria para atualizar as imagens inseridas no banco de dados?

Comment: Essa resposta foi correta para o sua pergunta, Marcelo?

Answer (score 2):

Tem sim como atualizar o campo de fotos que está no tipo `LONGBLOB`.

## Scripts

***conexao.php:*** Responsável pela conexão com o banco MySQL feito em [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php)

```
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', 'root', 'senha');
```

---

***Index.php:*** Responsável em inserir, alterar e listar as fotos que estão gravados no banco com o campo `LONGBLOB`

```
<?php    
    include 'conexao.php';
    //função responsável em converto arquivo de imagem em bytes
    function renderBytePicture($arq){        
        return fread(fopen($arq, "rb"), filesize($arq));
    }

    //verificação dos valores enviados pelos inputs e files da tela
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $im = isset($_FILES['imagem']) ? $_FILES['imagem']: NULL;
   
    //verifica se a imagem foi enviada
    if (is_null($im) === false)
    {
        //pega extensão da foto
        $imgs = explode('.',$im['name']);
        //cria um nome temporário do arquivo foto enviado
        $nametemp = session_id().'tmp-.'.(date('dmYHis')).'.'.(end($imgs));
        //envia a foto para o diretório
        move_uploaded_file($im['tmp_name'], $nametemp);
        //converte o arquivo de foto em bytes
        $imagem = renderBytePicture($nametemp);
        //verifica se o id foi digitado se não ele inseri se sim ele altera
        if (empty($id)) // novo registro
        {
            $sts = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO imagens(imagem, type, size) VALUES (?,?,?);');
            $sts->bindValue(1, $imagem, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
            $sts->bindValue(2, $im['type'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sts->bindValue(3, filesize($nametemp), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sts->execute();            
        } 
        else // alterar registro
        {
            $sts = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE imagens SET imagem=?, type=?, size=? WHERE id=?;');
            $sts->bindValue(1, $imagem, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
            $sts->bindValue(2, $im['type'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sts->bindValue(3, filesize($nametemp), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sts->bindValue(4, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sts->execute();
        }
        
        unlink($nametemp);
    }
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Enviando em alterando foto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>Para Alterar Informe Id:</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="id" value="" id="id"></div>
        <div>Escolha a Imagem:</div>
        <div><input type="file" name="imagem" id="imagem"></div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Código</td>
            <td>Foto</td>
        <tr>
        <?php
            foreach($pdo->query('SELECT id, imagem FROM imagens ORDER BY id') as $item):            
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $item['id'];?></td>
            <td><img src="render.php?id=<?php echo $item['id'];?>" width="100px" /></td>
        <tr>
        <?php
            endforeach;
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

***render.php:*** Responsável em mostrar a imagem

```
<?php
  $id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);    
  if (empty($id) === false){
      include 'conexao.php';
      
      $sts = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, imagem, type, size FROM imagens WHERE id=? limit 1');
      $sts->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $sts->execute();
      $item = $sts->fetch();
            
      header("Content-type: ".$item['type']);
      echo $item['imagem'];
  }
```

---

***Layout da tabela***

```
CREATE TABLE `imagens` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imagem` longblob NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

***Tela resultante***

A tela funciona assim: se você informar a caixa de texto o código para alteração escolher a foto e enviar ele altera a foto, se você escolher somente a foto e não informar a caixa de texto ele insere a foto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]