# Exibir imagem BMP salva no Oracle em PHP

Tags: php, oracle, imagem

Como fazer para recuperar uma imagem BMP salva em um banco Oracle e exibi-la na tela Infelizmente não posso armazenar os arquivos das imagens no servidor e guardar no banco apenas o caminho.

Comment: Eu tenho essa resposta aqui amigo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14240/atualizar-campo-longblob-e-possivel/14255#14255, o que muda ai é a forma de conexão

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas formas de se fazer isso sem gravar a imagem no servidor, uma delas é como o [FCCDias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6026/fccdias) explica em [Atualizar campo LONGBLOB é possível?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14240/atualizar-campo-longblob-e-possivel/14255#14255)

Uma outra forma é converter a imagem em base 64 e exibir embutindo o código base 64 na tag `img`do html:

```
$imagem_64 = base64_encode($res['imagem']); //$res é o resultado de sua consulta ao Oracle
echo '<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,'+$imagem_64+'" />';
```

Desta forma, na tag `img` ao invés de inserir uma URL como normalmente faríamos, inserimos a própria imagem.